# How to import DirectX or OpenGL for visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, opengl, import, directx

I was wondering if it was possible to install DirectX or OpenGL to optimize in my VB programs. Also, are there any other alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of older tutorials are going to point you to using the legacy Managed DirectX 1.1 assemblies. Don't use them. See [DirectX and .NET](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2010/12/09/directx-and-net/) for why.

[SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) or [SlimDX](https://slimdx.org/) is the way to go these days for using DirectX from managed languages like C# or VB.

Comment: I don't see why this got downvoted. The answerer is telling the OP not to use Managed DX and gives him up-to-date alternatives. Sure, he could've given a brief explanation to why he shouldn't use Managed DX and not _only_ rely on the link, but it's still a good answer.